Spacing between mathrel and mathord same as between mathrel and mathopen
According to the table in TeX by Topic a thick space is inserted between a relation and an ordinary atom and thin one between a relation and an opening atom.

where 0 is no space, 1 a thin space, 2 a medium space, and 3 a thick space.
But in the following code it seems to insert a thick space in both cases. Is there something I have overlooked?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathrlap{\to (x)} \mkern-5mu\mathcolor{red}{\to {(}x)} \\
  \mathrlap{\mathcolor{green}{a\mskip\thinmuskip b}}
  \mathrlap{a\mskip\medmuskip b}
  \mathcolor{red}{a\mskip\thickmuskip b} \\
  \mathrlap{\mathcolor{green}{\to {(}}}
  \mathrlap{\mathrel{\to} \mathopen{(}}
  \mathcolor{red}{{\to}\mskip\medmuskip{(}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}



this looks like a typo in TeX by topic. In the table in the TeXbook there are only (3), * and 0 on the Rel line.

TbT table also differs from the version of the table that is in the LaTeX Companion V2 (I had it bookmarked)

TLC3 has it on page 210 in Vol II. TbT seems incorrect.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you! Is it possible to get it fixed in the TeX by Topic version on CTAN?

@EuklidAlexandria That will be up to the author of TbT

TeX by Topic is wrong here. The original table in the TeXbook looks like this


TeX inserts a thick space between a relation symbol and an opening atom. The following table has been taken from the TeXbook (see this answer for reference

The indices in the left column and the top row refer to the math category, in particular 3 for relations and 4 for openings (I is for inner atoms). In the body of the table, 0 means no space, 1 a thin space, 2 a medium space and 3 a thick space. The parentheses mean that the corresponding spacing is only added in display or text styles. The asterisk denotes an impossible combination.
The table in TeX by Topic has typos.
